# Hide span if ID variable is 0

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried numerous solutions to this that I've found here and none work. Either I don't know what I'm doing or my situation is unique.

I have span IDs that count the number of specific div classes on a page. For example:

```
var numNew = $('.new').length;
document.getElementById('numNewOutput').innerHTML = numNew;
```

which counts the number of divs with the class "new" corresponds to

```
<tr style="color:var(--new);"><td><span class="tallynum" id="numNewOutput"></span></td><td class="tallyhead">NEW</td></tr>
```

Which puts that value into the span.

This works perfectly, BUT if the value is 0, I want it to be hidden. There a multiple spans with the same class and unique IDs that pull different div counts.
A working page is here (the tallys I am addressing appear when you click "Shit I've watched & read" at the top): http://rubbersquare.com/watched2023/

Some (not all) of the other variables are

```
var numNewfilm = $('.newfilm').length;
    document.getElementById('numNewfilmOutput').innerHTML = numNewfilm;
    var numNewnonfictionfilm = $('.newnonfictionfilm').length;
    document.getElementById('numNewnonfictionfilmOutput').innerHTML = numNewnonfictionfilm;
    var numNewepisode = $('.newepisode').length;
    document.getElementById('numNewepisodeOutput').innerHTML = numNewepisode;
    var numNewnonfictionepisode = $('.newnonfictionepisode').length;
    document.getElementById('numNewnonfictionepisodeOutput').innerHTML = numNewnonfictionepisode;
    var numNewshort = $('.newshort').length;
    document.getElementById('numNewshortOutput').innerHTML = numNewshort;
```

with HTML:

```
<tr style="color:var(--new);"><td><span class="tallynum" id="numNewOutput"></span></td><td class="tallyhead">NEW</td></tr>
<tr style="color:var(--new);"><td><span class="tallynum" id="numNewfilmOutput"></span></td><td class="tallyname">films</td></tr>
<tr style="color:var(--new;)"><td><span class="tallynum" id="numNewnonfictionfilmOutput"></span></td><td class="tallyname">nonfiction films</td></tr>
<tr style="color:var(--new;)"><td><span class="tallynum" id="numNewepisodeOutput"></span></td><td class="tallyname">episodes</td></tr>  
<tr style="color:var(--new;)"><td><span class="tallynum" id="numNewnonfictionepisodeOutput"></span></td><td class="tallyname">nonfiction episodes</td></tr>  
<tr style="color:var(--new;)"><td><span class="tallynum" id="numNewshortOutput"></span></td><td class="tallyname">shorts</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how it could be done:

```
const numNew = document.querySelectorAll('.new').length;
const output = document.querySelector('#numNewOutput');
if (numNew) {
  output.textContent = numNew;
} else {
  output.hidden = true;
}
```

P.S.
Please don't mix jquery selectors with vanilla js selectors.

And never use `var`

Comment: That works, but only for the first one. If I add the same code again and update to the  other variables (numNewfilm .newfilm numNewfilmOutput) all of the numbers disappear.

Comment: @Rubbersquare, please include your "other variables" in your original post so we can get an idea of the entire problem.

Comment: I added some to the original post. Basically they follow "new" in the original post and answer with others following the pattern of "newfilm" "newnonfictionfilm" "newepisode" "newnonfictionepisode" "newshort" - then there's "rewatch" then "rewatchfilm" "rewatchnonfictionfilm" etc.

Comment: I don't see a reason why wouldn't my code work with your data.

Comment: You are overriding `window.onload` with new functions. Add everything into one function.

Comment: It does. I realized I need to have unique names for output, i.e. output1, output2, etc.